# JMX interoperatibility with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, jmx

I am testing interoperatibility between JMX and vbscript using samples given in Early Access 4

- I have setup environment by following steps given in index.html in samples' help
- I have also set up WinRM using the steps given in samples' help
- The server under vbscript runs as expected and prints the address service:jmx:ws://127.0.0.1:8745/wsman

  1. When I open Jconsole, SimpleAgent is listed in the "Local Processes"and I can connect to it and see management beans
  2. but when I put the same address in "Remote Address" and try to connect JConsole complains that it cannot connect without giving any details.
  3. If I run any script given in vbscript/client, it fails with error message "The WinRM client cannot process the request. The destination computer returned an invalid SOAP fault."

If I enable logging for #2 above no logs are generated but they are generated in #3.

When the logs are generated by step following #3, there is following exception but I don't know whether that can be the reason for getting the WinRM error message

> [java] Dec 17, 2013 4:32:18 PM com.sun.jmx.remote.ws.wsman.JMXWSManResourceIteratorFactory$ResourceIterator startPull [java] FINER: Exception while initializing Enumeration timeout : java.lang.IllegalStateException: reader must be on a START_ELEMENT event, not a 8 event

Does anyone has any idea as to why #3 fails (running vbscript to get MBeans) with error message "The WinRM client cannot process the request. The destination computer returned an invalid SOAP fault."?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was wrong JAXWS version. I was using the latest one (2.2.8) but that doesn't seem to work. You have to use 2.1.4.